# Merge multiple data frames that have different columns numbers and names

Tags: r

I have more than 30 data frames 
I read it into R in the following way:

```
                    file.list <- list.files(pattern='*.csv')
                    df.list <- lapply(file.list, read.csv)
```

Now, what is the most efficient way to merge all that data frames in a single data set, some columns across the data frames have different names. Also, column number is different.
Thanks

Comment: do you want all of dataframes to have the same column names or is it ok for them to be different? if you don't care if the columns line up something like this should work `do.call(dplyr::bind_rows,df.list)`

Comment: or use `data.table`s `rbindlist`: `result <- rbindlist(df.list, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: Mike: thank you ---- well I need to explore both... that datasets contain a large number of col. I am trying to figure out a way to put it together without losing Info